# pin request at the startup lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note, vpn

I was trying to set up a VPN connection and it asked me about medium and high level security and a password which I didn't understand well! I failed to use VPN but now each time I try to unlock the phone, it asks for that password/pin. I removed the created VPN connection to get rid of it but to no avail. How can I remove this pin request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Security -> Screen lock`, enter the PIN once more and select `Slide` (or what ever you had before).

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other posted methods work, try the following solution, which solved this problem for me.

Open Settings and then navigate to `More` and then `Security` and tap `Clear Credentials`. After that you can navigate to `My Device` and then `Lock Screen` where you can change the screen lock to whatever you desire.

I'm not sure what other credentials it clears besides the screen lock but I haven't found anything so far.

I've tested this on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1. The exact locations and names of different settings may be located in different places depending on your device.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem for my galaxy note 2. I fixed it by following these steps:

1. Go to settings from the menu button on the home screen.
2. click "my device".
3. click "lock screen".
4. click "screen lock".
5. enter your passcode.
6. click whichever security setting you used before.